# importing flatbuffers correctly with typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, flatbuffers

In typescript I am using flatbuffers like this:

```
import {flatbuffers} from 'flatbuffers';
const builder = new flatbuffers.Builder(1);
```

then I compile to js to be use with react-native:

```
const flatbuffers_1 = require("flatbuffers");
const builder = new flatbuffers_1.flatbuffers.Builder(1);
```

but I get error:

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'new flatbuffers_1.flatbuffers.Builder')
```

What happen?

Comment: Have you tried following this: http://google.github.io/flatbuffers/flatbuffers_guide_use_typescript.html

Comment: @Alvin did you ever get this working. I am trying to use flat buffers in Javascript with React Native (Expo fork). It works fine in a browser but on Android I get the `undefined is not an object` error like you did. My `flatbuffers` object is undefined... I checked the files and I'm wondering if it's something to do with the use of `namespace` and `global`.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct solution, but I'm using the more modern approach/ ES6 imports, and its working fine when I do the following:

```js
import {flatbuffers} from "flatbuffers";
const builder = new flatbuffers.Builder(6000);
// ...
```

Though I had to modify the code gen output in the generated class from `import * as flatbuffers from 'flatbuffers';` to `import {flatbuffers} from 'flatbuffers';`